# SQL Server 2008 SELECT JOIN from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have two tables, the first one looks like this:

**[Comparisons]**

- Id (int)
- Car_Id1 (int)
- Car_Id2 (int)
- Slug (string)
- TimeStamp

The second one:

**[VehicleSpecs]**

- Id (int)
- Year (int)
- Make (string)
- Model (string)

I have this query

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM [Comparsions] 
WHERE 
ORDER BY [TimeStamp]
```

It returns the newest 100 records, but I need to replace the `Car_Id1` and `Car_Id2` with information from the second table like this: `Car_Id1 -> [Year + Make + Model]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you'll need is two `INNER JOIN`s against the `VehicleSpecs` table, one for each `Car_Id1` and `Car_Id2`.  I've aliased them as `car1, car2`.

```
SELECT TOP 100
  c.Id,
  c.Slug,
  c.TimeStamp,
  /* Select the relevant columns from *both* of the joined tables */
  /* And give each column an alias to differentiate it from the other */
  car1.Year AS car1Year,
  car1.Make AS car1Make,
  car1.Model AS car1Model,
  car2.Year AS car2Year,
  car2.Make AS car2Make,
  car2.Model AS car2Model
FROM 
  Comparisons c
  /* Join first against VehicleSpecs for Car_Id1 */
  INNER JOIN VehicleSpecs car1 ON c.Car_Id1 = car1.Id
  /* Then once more for Car_Id2 */
  INNER JOIN VehicleSpecs car2 ON c.Car_Id2 = car2.Id
ORDER BY c.TimeStamp
```

You said you wanted the *newest*, so I assume you actually mean to use descending order on the timestamps:

```
ORDER BY c.TimeStamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Join against the second table twice:

```
select top 100
  c.Id, c.Slug, c.TimeStamp,
  s1.Year as Car1_Year, s1.Make as Car1_Make, s1.Model as Car1_Model,
  s2.Year as Car2_Year, s2.Make as Car2_Make, s2.Model as Car2_Model
from Comparsions c
inner join VehicleSpecs s1 on s1.Id = c.Car_Id1
inner join VehicleSpecs s2 on s2.Id = c.Car_Id2
order by c.TimeStamp desc
```

(Side note: You might want to correct the table name to `Comparisons`.)